# Gravity Forms Total Field not working in Wordpress Pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have wordpress with gravity forms plugin to add forms with a product and options and the total down the bottom.

When I create the form and click "preview" the total down the bottom works, but the problem is when I insert the same form into a page, the total at the bottom is $0 and when I tick the checkboxes for extras like $200 etc the total remains at $0.

When I submit and go to paypal the correct total is there so it appears an issue with the display

Also the text (+$200) appears after option fields in the preview but not when I put onto wordpress pages. I have tried in Chrome, Firefox, IE and same thing, total is $0 no matter what options I check

I am using Studiopress Genesis theme but have tried switching to basic WP themes like TwentyFourteen and makes no difference. Have tried disabling most plugins but also no luck.
Does work on another blank wordpress site though

I suspect something on the page is interfering, a solution may be to create a page template that just has the form and not all the other javascripts and junk. All I would really want is my logo up the top and then the form. So even some help just to get a plain page with the form like how it looks in the preview window would do

Just to clarify the form totals work in preview and if inserted into posts, but not in pages on this studiopress genesis site, any idea what could be interfering?

Also FYI if you tick on the top right hand side "Disable Sharebar on this post?" that causes the whole form to disappear

Would really appreciate any help, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what solved it for me is I made sure that the jQuery was loaded in the Header and not the footer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and had to use a gravity forms filter function to fix it. Documentation is found [here](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_product_total)

Adding the following javascript code to my page fixed the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){
    return total; //amount you wish to display in the Total 
 } );
</script>
```

You can add javascript code via page template, create a custom shortcode, use one of many plugins that allow the insertion of javascript on a page, or add the code into an HTML form block within the gravity forms form.